# pandas devide column by another one safely ( zeros, None, str)

Tags: pandas, dataframe

How to divide one column by another one zero and str safe? 
I don't want to create new 'A' and 'B' cols without zeros and str for some reason. If devision is not possible, I want to get Nones.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, None, 2, 1 ,5], 'B': [1, 3,'', 'cat', 4]})
```

I try:

```
df['C'] = df['B'].divide(df['A'], fill_value=None) # error with zero devision
```

In fact, this works, but maybe there is more elegant way?

```
`df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['B']/row['A'] if isinstance(row['A'], numbers.Number) and isinstance(row['B'], numbers.Number) and row['A'] != 0 else None, axis = 1) # this works perfectly but looks ugly`
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.to_numeric` to coerce non-numeric types:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df['C'] = pd.to_numeric(df['B'], errors='coerce').divide(pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce'))

#     A    B    C
#0  0.0    1  inf
#1  NaN    3  NaN
#2  2.0       NaN
#3  1.0  cat  NaN
#4  5.0    4  0.8
```

If you don't want `np.inf` then:

```
df['C'] = df.C.replace(np.inf, np.NaN)
```